# Testing a Service which is using TranslateService

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have the following Service

```
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class RuleCalculationService2 {

    constructor(private readonly translateService: TranslateService) {}

    getCalculationRuleLabel(costItem: SingleCostItem): string {
        
        return this.translateService.instant(something}`)
    }
```

the test for this service looks like this

```
describe('RuleCalculationService', () => {
    let service: RuleCalculationService2;
    let mockTranslateService: jasmine.SpyObj<TranslateService>;
    let costItem;

    beforeEach(() => {
        mockTranslateService = jasmine.createSpyObj<TranslateService>('TranslateService', ['instant']);

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                RuleCalculationService2,
                {provide: TranslateService, useValue: mockTranslateService},
            ]
        });

        service = TestBed.inject(RuleCalculationService2);

})

it('should return the label...',() => {
                    
                    mockTranslateService.instant.and.callThrough();

                    
                  expect(service.getCalculationRuleLabel(costItem)).toEqual('something');
                }
            );

})
```

i expect that when i call mockTranslateService.instant.and.callThrough() Jasmine to execute the actual implementation of the spied method when it is invoked, but this is not happening and im getting "expexted undefinded to equal something"

can someone tell me what im doing wrong ?

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to test TranslateSerivice? If I were you I would just add mock return value to `instant`, and that's about it. You expect `something` but you never return it.

Comment: I want service.getCalculationRuleLabel(costItem) to call the translateService itself so that i can perform an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution, I want to use the real translateService and i want to provide it using TranslateModule.forRoot()

```
let service: RuleCalculationService2;
    let translateService: TranslateService;
    let costItem;

    beforeEach(() => {
        
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [RuleCalculationService2], 
            imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot()]
        });

        service = TestBed.inject(RuleCalculationService2);
        translateService = TestBed.inject(TranslateService);
        spyOn(translateService, 'instant').and.callThrough();
```

importing TranslateModule.forRoot() in the testBead then providing it and injecting it in the service, from there on using callThrough() ensures that at the beginning of every test i have the real instance of the translateService and now Karma knows what to do when she sees this.translateService.instant() in the testing environment